# How to print email's attachments in Outlook Express automatically?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, printing

Like in title. I need to print email's attachment automatically. It prints message's header only. Is there any way to do that ?

Comment: Are you asking about **Microsoft Office Outlook** or about **Outlook Express**? They are not the same thing, and Outlook Express should be dead and buried. The last version of Windows it supported was XP, and - like IE6 - it no longer receives security fixes.

Comment: Well. An Employee works at Windows Server 2003 terminal so he cant really use Office Outlook. He is forced to use Outlook Express

Comment: Outlook will run on Server 2003 (which is nearly as obsolete as XP), though if you're getting email on your server there's probably already something wrong. Still, OK, at least you did actually mean Outlook Express.